# C# - Números primos aleatórios?

Tags: c#

Tenho um exercício da faculdade que é gerar um número primo aleatório, se esse número não for primo ele deve ficar gerando outro aleatório ate que um seja, mas ele sempre cai em números que não são primos e ficam em loop infinito, o que será que estou fazendo de errado no código?
Agradeço desde já a ajuda de todos.

Segue código abaixo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int p, div = 0;
        bool nPrimo = false;

        Random r = new Random();

        p = r.Next(1, 100);

        while (nPrimo == false)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++)
            {
                if (p % i == 0)
                {
                    div++;
                }

            }
            if (div == 2)
            {
                nPrimo = true;
            }

            else
            {
                p = r.Next(1,100);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim como o @Thiago já disse, faltou de fato voltar a colocar os divisores(a variavel `div`) a `0` no fim do `while`. No entanto se estruturar com funções acaba por ficar mais simples e esse problema nem é possível de acontecer.

Veja o mesmo programa estruturado com uma função de verificação de primo:

```
public static bool ePrimo(int num){
    int div = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            div++;
        }   
    }

    return div == 2; //true se div for 2, falso caso contrário
}

public static void Main()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int p = r.Next(1, 100);

    //aqui testa se não é primo, e executa enquanto não for primo
    while (!ePrimo(p)) 
    {
        p = r.Next(1,100);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

[Veja este exemplo no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LO29gP)

Ainda havia muitas optimizações da verificação do primo que podia fazer, mas já fogem um pouco ao foco da pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica !!

Answer (score 4):

Você esqueceu de resetar o número de divisores pra 0, a cada início de iteração do while.

Tendo em vista que a variável só é utilizada em um lugar, ficaria mais claro se você a declarasse dentro do while.

Comment: Vlw !!! era um negocio tão simples  e eu quebrando a cabeça.
E obrigado pela dica quanto a variável, vou fazer desta forma.

Comment: Você pode aceitar a resposta como válida se ajudou. :)

Comment: Aprendendo as funcionalidades do site também, resposta mais que aceita, agradeço novamente pela ajuda !!!